# See PIDs only by specific users in bash

Tags: bash, command-line, process, pid

So I'm having some troubles in finding a way to isolate the PIDs from top using pipelines and not being able to use`awk` or `perl`. So far I'm able to isolate the specific Users (Cannot be your username or root) and now I'm not sure how to move on from here, I've tried using `cut` and several other options but it's not working. Here's my work so far:

```
top -n 1 | tail -n +8 | grep -Ev '\broot\b | \bmyUserName\b`
```

This outputs all the information minus the heading, and I need to remove everything else but the PIDs... Could anyone help at all?

EDIT: Also, right now what *seems* to work is just adding `| cut -c 4-11` which shows only the PID, because there is only one other user that is not root on the system. I'm not sure it will work if there's more, but is there any better ideas as to how to make it work?

Comment: The "do not use the obvious tools" requirement comes from the course exercise?  Or is there some other reason to run with one hand tied behind your back?  In particular, `awk` with its auto-splitting on columns is entirely appropriate for the job. I assume the `tail -n +8` is simply cutting down the amount of output while you're testing?

Comment: Yeah, it's the course requirement that we do not use either of these, hence why I'm not sure how to continue with this. And yeah, `tail -n +8` just cuts down the header information (Everything above PID   USER etc)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85466/how-to-see-process-created-by-specific-user-in-unix-linux just extend that answer with `ps -ef | grep "^\(user_1\|user_n\)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory:

```
top -n 1 | tail -n +8 | grep -Ev ' root | myUserName ' |
sed -e 's/^[ ]*\([0-9][0-9]*\) .*/\1/'
```

The `sed` command looks for start of line, optional blanks followed by a number and a blank and trailing garbage.  However, this doesn't work because `top` generates screen control characters:

```
28433 jleffler  20   0 1511m 403m  31m S    2  1.3  70:35.76 chrome
```

looks OK, but when pushed through a hex dump, the output is:

```
0x0000: 1B 28 42 1B 5B 6D 32 38 34 33 33 20 6A 6C 65 66   .(B.[m28433 jlef
0x0010: 66 6C 65 72 20 20 32 30 20 20 20 30 20 31 35 31   fler  20   0 151
0x0020: 30 6D 20 34 30 34 6D 20 20 33 31 6D 20 53 20 20   0m 404m  31m S  
0x0030: 20 20 34 20 20 31 2E 33 20 20 37 30 3A 33 37 2E     4  1.3  70:37.
0x0040: 38 37 20 63 68 72 6F 6D 65 20 20 20 20 20 20 20   87 chrome
```

To suppress that, use `top -b` (batch mode):

```
top -b -n 1 | tail -n +8 | grep -Ev ' root | myUserName ' |
sed -e 's/^[ ]*\([0-9][0-9]*\) .*/\1/'
```

This should generate a list of PIDs; it did for me.

If you were allowed `awk`, you might simplify that to:

```
top -b -n 1 | awk 'NR<=8 || $2~/^(root|myUserName)$/ {next} {print $1}'
```

And all this is predicated on 'Using `top` is a good way to go', rather than using `ps` (which is the normal tool to use for gathering PIDs.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even think of using sed, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the PID's of all processes not spawned by `root` or `some_user` then you could list these processes using `ps` with `-U user` and the negation option `-N`:

```
ps -U root -U some_user -N -o pid
```

The `-o` option specifies that we're only interested in the PID in the output.
Now you can easily do something with these PID's in a loop or similar:

```
for pid in $(ps -U root -U some_user -N -o pid); do
    # something to $pid
done
```